# XElement.Descendants () make it case-insensitive

Tags: xml, linq, xpath, xelement, descendant

XElement.Descendants () method accepts name of element to be find.

But it is case-sensitive is there any way to make it case-insensitive

Answer (score 9):

You can use this:

```
element.Descendants()
       .Where(x => string.Compare(x.Name, filter,
                                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

Comment: If there is any chance of any issue when this method

Comment: @user1750877: What kind of issue are you thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me..

```
XElement selectedElement = doc.Descendants().Where(x => 
String.Equals((string)x.Attribute("name"), filtertext, 
StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
```