# How to convert XElement to lowercase?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

This is my code. I essentially want it to return the descendants regardless of the string case.

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(myReader.ReadSubtree());
IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = doc.Descendants(es + family).Descendants(es + parameterName.Trim());
```

If `family` is "Jones", but in the XML it's "jones", then nothing is found. The same thing happens with `parameterName`.

Is there any way to change `XElement doc` to lowercase? That way I can use `String.ToLower` on both `family` and `parameterName`.

I found this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977166/xelement-descendants-make-it-case-insensitive), but I don't know how to implement that solution here.

Since I rarely use linq, and I know that the previous code works, I tried going step-by-step and used the `where` extension, but it didn't return anything:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = doc.Descendants(es + family).Where(node => (string)node.Attribute(family) == family)
    .Descendants(es + parameterName.Trim()).Where(node => (string)node.Attribute(parameterName) == parameterName);
```

Since this change didn't return anything, I didn't go beyond that.

I also tried the following code, and I get a run error in the first where extension:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = 
    doc.Descendants(es + family).Where(node => node.Attribute(family).ToString().ToLower() == family.ToLower())
    .Descendants(es + parameterName.Trim()).Where(node2 => node2.Attribute(parameterName).ToString().ToLower() == parameterName.ToLower());
```

Comment: What problems did you encounter when you tried the solution suggested in the linked question?

Comment: You just need to call the `Where` extension method twice. It's basically copy-paste. Try it and if it doesn't work, post your code.

Comment: I posted what I've tried; instead of going straight to the possible solution, I simply added the `where` extension on code that I already knew works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Equals` method it allows ignoring case:

```
.Where(node => ((string)node.Attribute(family)).Equals(family,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

I used Ordinal comparison but there are others available in the StringComparison enum.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I get build error `'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`.

Comment: Even if it worked, I would still need to get the descendants with `parameterName`

Comment: @user3605366 I added a modification for you. I missed a set of parentheses. Use the same idea when getting the parameterName. If this still doesn't work, add a sample of the xml code.  I suspect your not accessing it right.

Comment: I get error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: The code I used with your suggestions: `IEnumerable<XElement> query1 =  doc.Descendants(es + family).Where(node => ((string)node.Attribute(family)).Equals(family,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Descendants(es + parameterName.Trim()).Where(node => ((string)node.Attribute(parameterName)).Equals(parameterName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`

Comment: My initial code (below) worked well, the only problem was that that it was case-sensitive, and that's what I need to eliminate: `XElement doc = XElement.Load(myReader.ReadSubtree());
IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = doc.Descendants(es + family).Descendants(es + parameterName.Trim());`

Comment: @user3605366 - Like I said you'll need to submit a sample of the xml code

Comment: The problem is that the block of code is over 4k lines. But I'm working on it.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm using `XNamespace` class, so the initial error wasn't a problem with parenthesis. If I use the string `family` with `Equals`, I don't get the error. But if I add the namespace `es`, then I get the error `'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

Comment: This builds: `.Where(node => ((string)node.Attribute(family)).Equals(family,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`.

Comment: This doesn't because I added `XNamespace es`: `.Where(node => ((string)node.Attribute(es + family)).Equals(es + family,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCas‌​e))`.

Comment: OK.  That's one reason I was asking about the xml code.  That sort of thing would have been easier for me to see.

Comment: I apologize about that; I wish I could just post the XML but it's just too big and it's confidential. But the initial code shows the `es` and I mentioned that, except for it not being case-sensitive, it parses the XML correctly.